# modify xml document using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, flash

So what I want do is create a jquery that will automatically remove/comment out information located in a xml document based on a expiration date. I am trying to create a slideshow for a movie theater that drops movies off after the last showing.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Your title suggests that you want to _modify_ an XML document. Then you have to create an updated XML document and then send it to the server using the `jQuery.ajax()` function. However, I don't see any reason for not doing that server-side. I guess what you probably mean is that you want _filter_ information from your downloaded XML document?

Comment: Yes that would be what I was trying to get at sorry it wasnt clearer I dont do alot of work with Jquery

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method, e.g:

```
var items = $(xml).find("item").filter(function() {
      return conditionToCheck;
});
```